# CheckBox was not invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have check box which I want the if its true display the next field (which is upload file here),and when I click on it nothing happen ,i.e. the view is not refreshed ,any idea how to solve it ? Since I'm Very new to Java script maybe I miss something

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {

                    $("#Visible").change(function () {
                        var checked = $(this).attr("checked");
                        if (checked) {
                            $("#File").show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#File").hide();
                         }
                    });
                });
            </script>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Visible, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Visible)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Visible)
        </div>
    </div>


        <div class="form-group">

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try `$(function () {
    $("#Visible").change(function () {
        $("#File").toggle(this.checked);
    });
});`

Comment: What's your rendered HTML markup look like?

Comment: @Felix- how should I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
$(function ()
 {     
      $("#Visible").change(function () 
      {         
        $("#File").toggle(this.checked);     
       }); 
 });
```